# Which animals taste different by sex?

Tags: food

I know of [Boar taint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boar_taint) which describes an unpleasant taste in the meat of non-castrated pigs. 
Which left me wondering more broadly: Are there other animals whose meat (from an animal of the *same age* on the same diet) tastes different depending on whether it came from a male or a female of the species?

(Originally [asked this on Cooking.SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/57003/35182), but apparently there aren't many eaters of game or "bush" meat there!)

Comment: I know game meat tends to taste 'gamey' certainly but I've never noticed between gender, certainly never noticed it with Pheasant ... But red wine gravy probably smothers any differences.

Comment: Male and female pheasant does taste different @Aravona male pheasant the taste is much stronger. Mostly butchers only sell the females

Comment: @Liam ahh we get both from a local farm for free, like I said after that much red wine gravy... I've never noticed! Might prepare them differently next time just to see a taste difference!

Comment: I think that might be dependant on whether you've hung the pheasant and for how long.

Comment: White tail deer taste different. Doe meat is way more tender. I knew a guy that only ate doe, and would give away all his buck meat.

Comment: @ShemSeger - are you sure that's not an age effect?  Most game laws prohibit killing young bucks and/or encourage hunters to take the most mature bucks, and it _does_ seem to be the case that older animals get tougher and taste worse, regardless of gender.

Comment: @feetwet Could have been. All I know is that the guy said he liked doe meat better, then he handed us a bunch of buck meat.

Comment: How is this an Outdoor question?  In principle all animals and plants grow outdoor (apart from modern industry farming) so then one could ask any food-related question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about outdoor recreation.

Comment: @gerrit It's essentially a question about "bush meat."  _Only_ outdoorsmen would know the answer.

Comment: @gerrit Because it's a hunting-related question?

Comment: Note that the animals need not have been hunted.  Somebody who farms exotic animals might be able to answer.  Outdoorsmen who eat carrion might be able to answer.  Of course, sport hunters with diverse experience are probably most likely to be able to answer.

Comment: This isn't exactly game, but free-range rooster is all red meat. Hens are still white meat. It's definitely not the tastier of the two. ...or it could just be psychological: My Peruvian friend, proud of his English, announced that we would be eating _cock_ that night.

Comment: This question is essentially about biology.  I see no reason why the answer should depend on the method of killing (i.e. hunting), the same answer applies whether the animal was killed through hunting, fishing, slaughtering, or died a peaceful death.  I would ask it on cooking or biology.

Comment: @gerrit: Biologists don't typically taste the specimens they study.  They might be able to explain _why_ flavors change (e.g., in some males like pigs it's due to the high levels of adenosteroids and related effects).  And I asked on Cooking.SE but, as noted in the OP, so far only one user has had any experience with eating males and females of the same species and age, and those were farmed .  Since relatively few species are farmed the question is most likely answerable by people with a lot of experience or knowledge of bush meat.  I.e., outdoorsmen.

Comment: I'm tempted to re-phrase it to apply to game only, hunting would be on-topic. But even then the relevance to *the outdoors* is tenuous. There's also an argument to say that this is simply a list question and doesn't have any specific answer. Reluctantly voting to close.